# Spring Integration Poller using jdbc

Tags: spring, jdbc

Wants to achieve some thing like

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="selectNUpdate" 
    query="select * from table1 where col1='abc' and rownum=1"
    update="update table1 set col2=0 where id in (:id)"
    data-source="dataSource">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1"
        fixed-rate="3000" /> 
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I want to just do a select query and based on the record update the record in the same table.
Problem is : In above spring xml if i would not give channel ="" then it fails with the exception "subscriber channel is not configured"

What is the way to achieve this i.e some poller which do a select  and update using jdbc

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear why you can't do that directly using `JdbcTemplate`...

But to answer just to your question, I can suggest to use built-in `nullChannel`

Comment: Thanks Artem.Could you suggest some

Comment: Thanks Artem its work for me .... Could you suggest some good Spring integration tutorial

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If it works, accept the answer, please, to close the question. The good tutorial is Spring IO site. The good book is "Spring Integration in Action"